# Why are questions closed with no reasoning to the owner?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, closed-questions

I had a question that was closed and I feel it was done with bad reason:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14669030/how-to-program-for-leapfrogs-leappad

My question is not why it was closed, at this point, however. My question is, why are people not forced to leave a reasoning beyond the generic choice of reason for close? If my question IS to be closed, do I not deserve the ability to view why each person chose to close it? How can I improve? Is my question (this one specifically) not welcome here? I am specifically asking how to program for a device, if I can't ask that here, where can I? I think we should be given more reasoning so that we know what we did wrong when posting. The canned generic response does not fit my post.

Comment: There *is* reasoning: *"It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, see the FAQ."*

Comment: The entirety of your question is: _"I am looking to find out if there is any non-proprietary way to create an application for LeapFrog's LeapPad Explorer. In addition, if there is a way to get this application transferred to the LeapPad."_. This _reads_ like "someone go and do some Googling for me". You may not have meant it that way but that's how it reads. I agree with the closing of the question in its current and previous form.

Answer (score 18):

> My question is, why are people not forced to leave a reasoning beyond the generic choice of reason for close? If my question IS to be closed, do I not deserve the ability to view why each person chose to close it?

If people were forced to type in a custom reason for every off-topic, not constructive, or too localized question, we'd see far fewer of them closed and quality on Stack Overflow would suffer.  You're the one asking a question.  The responsibility is yours to read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) and ask questions that are on-topic here.  The burden of explaining that to each person asking a question should not fall on everyone else.